# How can I know the host name on client server program

Tags: linux, sockets, client-server, host

I am doing a program about client server communication using sockets. I saw examples of client server program on internet, but I have a question. How to get host name? I saw a client program example on the webpage int the link below. The program gets the host name from the user in command line arguments,but how can I know the host name? and I tried using my username on it but its says host does not found. I am running both on same machine. Thank you very much for your time.

client:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_client_example.htm

server:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host name is different from the username to get the host name use the command "hostname"
and use this host name in command line

commands:

hostname -->gethostname

hostname < name > -->sethostname with name

Comment: also how can I find port number? both client and serve will be running on same machine at the same time. can just assign any random number like 50001? Thank you.

Comment: while providing command line arguments you can specify the port no as you like (eg : 50001) port no is your choice but does not use 0 - 1024 port no because these are well known ports and are widely used by network stack

Answer (score 1):

If your client and server are on the same host, the hostname is `localhost`, or you could use the name of the machine, or you could use 127.0.0.1

Comment: so if I hard code that in my code, can it still run on other machines? Thank you.

Comment: Only if the other machines also have the server running on them.  If you want the server to only run on your machine, and have the client run on other machines, they need to refer to the hostname of your machine.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, I know what you mean. This is part of my home work, so my professor will be running both on his machine at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the host you are currently running on you use **[gethostname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname)**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    char buffer[100];

    if ((ret = gethostname(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) == -1)
    {
        perror("gethostname");
        exit(1);
    }    

    printf("hostname is: %s\n", buffer);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a client server program , the client must know the hostname or the ip address of the machine it wants to communicate with.

Think of it like you are driving to a particular shop, you need to know the address of the shop to  reach there. Similarly clients need the address of the host it needs to communicate with.

If you are running your own client and server, then type hostname in the machine and it will give you the host name. Usually you would need host name and port but in simple example programs the value may be hard coded.

Comment: Actually this is an assignment, so my TAs will be using their machines, so do you know what can I do for that? thank you.

Comment: will they be running both on the same machine, if not its valid to ask them to pass the host name.

Comment: then you can say localhost or use ip address 127.0.0.1

Comment: Choose one the answer as correct answer so that the thread can be closed